# Problem to upload a file to Gitlab using python-gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to upload a file to my gitlab repository using this way:

`x = project.upload("Jenkinsfile", filepath="./Jenkinsfile")` however it not work for me, so

`x1 = project.upload("Jenkinsfile", filepath="/media/conde/Trabajo/Trabajo/DevOps/BOMH/bomh/Jenkinsfile")` , not work, let's go to trying the documentation example because it not need a filesystem path, so it have at least to create a new file empty:

`x2 = project.upload("filename.txt", filedata="data")`

But never a file is uploaded. The output of each comand is:

`x={'url': '/uploads/c52cf003900c7afe6843909317049cc3/Jenkinsfile', 'markdown': 'Jenkinsfile', 'alt': 'Jenkinsfile'}`

`x1 = {'url': '/uploads/c52cf003900c7afe6843909317049cc3/Jenkinsfile', 'markdown': 'Jenkinsfile', 'alt': 'Jenkinsfile'}`

`x2 = {'url': '/uploads/3c2a389555609ba08c3bd54bee0e7339/filename.txt', 'markdown': 'filename.txt', 'alt': 'filename.txt'}`

What is wrong, the documentation, the API?
I can create the repository, the branchs and create some files, but not upload a file from my computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The truth that described in the documentation can be a bit ambiguous, the question is that the function project.upload not upload a file to the remote repository in Gitlab, just upload a file to the project, if you want to directly upload any initial file (like me that I'm automatically creating a initial gitlab repository with some files for a project using python-gitlab) a good solution is transfer the content from your local file to the new file that you are creating. In my case I did this:

```
with open('./file_to_upload', 'r') as my_file:
    file_content = my_file.read()
f = project.files.create({'file_path': 'template.json',
                              'branch': 'master',
                              'content': file_content,
                              'author_email': 'test@example.com',
                              'author_name': user_nick,
                              #'encoding': 'utf-8',
                              'commit_message': 'Create template.json'})
```